# Selenium can't find all elements by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium to crawl data of a website and conduct the code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromeDriverPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
url = 'https://shopee.vn/Th%E1%BB%9Di-Trang-Nam-cat.11035567?page=0'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath)
driver.get(url)

try:
    main_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]'
    main = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,main_xpath))
    )
    product_list = main.find_elements(By.XPATH,'./div[@data-sqe="item"]')
    i=1
    for i in range(0,len(product_list)):
        print(i)
        print(product_list[i].text)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

but it returns only the first 15 non-empty elements and the rest are empty although it seems to return number element of `product_list` exactly .
So, how can i find all elements of `product_list` ?

Comment: What elements did you want? There are 60 elements with that tag but don't come up unless you scroll all the way down.

Comment: Looking at the website, it seems like the product lists are loaded as one scrolls down the page, so the script might need to scroll to the bottom of the page first before reading the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for i in range(1,int(len(product_list)/15)):
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", product_list[i*15])
         time.sleep(5)
```

Here's a hack I made to scroll 15 elements down and then wait a bit till it loads.